# C# add chart error DataVisualization.Charting - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, graph, charts

I'm trying to use Charts to create graphs in Visual Studio 2012. I have .Net 4.0
But when write this:
      `using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;`

i get an error:

`The type or namespace name 'DataVisualization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Forms'`
How can i solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add reference to the `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization` in the Solution Explorer panel.

Comment: And where can i find it?

Comment: In the VS 2012 IDE. At the right on the screen.  
Right click on the solution and select menu item "Add Reference..."

Comment: Thank you! I find it! but one problem... I can't add Chart in my Design, why?

Comment: To add Chart to a form in the designer, drag'n'drop it from the Toolbox. Chart item can be found in the "Data" section of toolbox.

Comment: i can't, because he doesn't exist. If i choose "Show all" it appears but i can not drag

Comment: And all other items are draggable? If so, create a new form and drag it there.

Answer (score 0):

Solution items are not used by compiled assemblies.
please follow this link.
[this is link for Complete charting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ee8zw5t.aspx)